# 404 error Flask with correct link

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on `flask` app, but whenever I try to run `run.py`, I get a `404`. Here is my views page:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, 

redirect, Flask, request
from app import app
import sqlite3 as sql
import csv
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
@app.route('/')
def home():
    print(10999)
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/2018_draft')
def list():
   con = sql.connect("database.db")
   con.row_factory = sql.Row

   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM BPM")

   rows = cur.fetchall();
   return render_template("table.html",rows = rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Ignoring the sqlite code, why am I getting a `404`? It doesn't work when I manually go to `localhost:5000/base.html`, or `localhost:5000/` or `localhost:5000/2018_draft` either.

Comment: It seems to work for me after removing the sql code and just returning text-no templates. I'm a bit confused by the line `from app import app` though, since you set `app = Flask(__name__)`. Can you edit your post to add the command line output?

Comment: This is all I see on command line, let me know if theres something else I can get                    
    127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2018 16:03:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Can you try what I did and replace `return render_template('base.html')` with `return "test"` to eliminate any other sources of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is on the path of templates, probably Flask can't find them.

Assuming that your file's name is run.py the organization of folders should be:

```
/parent_folder
    /static
    /templates
    run.py
```

/static is the folder that you put js/css files that your html may import.
/templates you put the html files that you want to render with  render_template("table.html",rows = rows)

I'm not sure why you import the `from app import app`, it is not necessary unless you create the `Flask(__name__)` in other file.